# slider getting stucked after refresh

Tags: magento2, frontend, slider, banner-slider

I am facing an issue using a slider in frontend of magento 2. Slider works perfectly at first load but gets stuck on refresh and only works after cache data of browser is cleared.

Link to website : http://www.i-ranu.com/

Herewith I have attached the images of frontend. First is the case when slider is working fine while next is when it is not. You can see the difference in the slider dots as well. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: It work fine now